# Data Sync issues between AEM and SOLR

Tags: solr, adobe, aem, solrcloud, aem-6

I use AEM to create pages and then push the content to SOLR using oak:index in the /crx/ page. Lets assume that I have a data as shown below:
Name : "xxx:
Age : "yyy"
Country : "zzz"
Now when I publish the page in AEM , the data gets indexed into SOLR. And when I edit a value in the above page ( eg: changing age to "aaa" ) and then if I publish it , then the data gets indexed into SOLR. But when I remove a value from that page and publish it , it is not getting reflected.
For eg: If I remove the value of age and then if I publish it , the old value of age still exists in SOLR.

How can this be handled ? Suggestions / Answers are most welcome !